# Is an HTTP URL containing // valid?

Tags: http, https

I have a URL in the following form

```
https://abc.domain.com//xyz/test
```

and I'm fetching the contents via Volley (Android).

Is it a valid URL? Do I need to one `/` remove from `//xyz`

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's still a valid URL. 
Both server and search engine consider these two (with `/` or `//`) are separated URLs.
So be sure what URL is correct for fetching.